# System.NotSupportedException: 'The current platform 'Android' does not support Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Popup.'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-community-toolkit, xamarin-forms-4

This exception is thrown when I try to add Xamarin's community tool kit's source code as a project in my solution, However it works correctly when I use the latest release from NuGet package manager

Comment: Have you tried lower the Target Android Version and Minimum Android Version?

Comment: I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Do you still meet this issue? If so, could you please share more detailed information such as target platform and api level,Xamarin Forms Version, Visual Studio Version and community toolkit version.